# Remove items from a list by comparing a date

Tags: java, list, date

I have the following method:

```
public List<List<String>> compareDate(List<List<String>> lists,String from, String to) {

    String dateFromLog;
    Date fromDate = null;
    Date toDate = null;

    SimpleDateFormat sdfToDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat sdfToDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

    try {
        fromDate = sdfToDate.parse(from);
        toDate = sdfToDate.parse(to);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i++) {
        dateFromLog = lists.get(i).get(0);
        try {
            Date logDate = sdfToDateTime.parse(dateFromLog);

            if (fromDate.before(logDate)) {
                lists.remove(i);
            } else if (toDate.after(logDate)) {
                lists.remove(i);
            }

        } catch (ParseException ex2) {
            ex2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return lists;
}
```

I have some troubles with the if in the try catch block. I want to delete each entry in this list, in which the logDate is before the fromDate and after the toDate. Unfortunetally it remove some list entrys but not all.

What i'm doing wrong here?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Use Iterator class to remove the element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't forward iterate over the list using an index and remove elements within that loop, since that way elements could be skipped.

The problem is the following:

Assume the elements at indices 2,3 and 4 match. Now you're at `i = 2` and remove element 2.
All following elements are moved so element 3 is now at index 2 and element 4 is at index 3. In the next iteration `i` will be increased to 3, thus you'll be checking element 4, effectively skipping element 3.

To fix that either iterate backwards or use an iterator.

The preferred way using an iterator:

```
for (Iteratory<List<String> itr = lists.iteator(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
  List<String> elementList = itr.next();
  ...

  if( ... ) {
    itr.remove();
  }
}
```

The reverse way (not preferred):

```
for (int i = lists.size() - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Great, many thanks for the fast answer and good explanation. I'll keep it in my mind :-)

Answer (score 3):

While iterating a `Collection`, element removal should be done *only* by means of [`Iterator.remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29). Or else, undefined behavior may happen.

```
for (Iterator<List<String>> it = lists.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    List<String> aList = it.next();
    if (mustRemove(aList)) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

From [The Collection Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html) in the Java Tutorials:

> Note that Iterator.remove is the only safe way to modify a collection during iteration; the behavior is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified in any other way while the iteration is in progress.

Also, if you're in a position to use third-party libraries, you could use Apache Commons' Collections [`CollectionUtils.filter()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20org.apache.commons.collections.Predicate%29) along with a `Predicate` that would remove unwanted elements from the `List`.